# Amazon Workdocs to S3 Problem with subscription following guide

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-workdocs

My company is trying to sync a folder from Workdocs to S3. I am currently using an AWS guide from here: https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/storage/auto-sync-files-from-amazon-workdocs-to-amazon-s3/. I am facing an issue in the point 7. Setting up the WorkDocs notification receiving these two errors:

- An error occurred (InternalFailure) when calling the CreateNotificationSubscription operation (reached max retries: 2): None
- An error occurred (ThrottlingException) when calling the CreateNotificationSubscription operation (reached max retries: 2): Rate exceeded

I have the logs from the Cloud Shell in case those are needed.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

These errors normally occurs when you are trying to use an invalid topic ARN.

Make sure that you using the correct ARN (eg. use the ARN of the Topic instead of the subscription or check if there are some typos on the ARN)

Comment: I was following the guide and it did not even mention anything about a topic at any point so I am not sure about the topic you are particularly specifying. Can you help me a little bit more? Because this is something I don't really know how to solve.